# Mainly front end, suggested back end task

Tags: software-industry, career-development, software-development, websites

I've been doing front end at my job lately (roughly three years). It is going OK. I did some other stuff too in this period using other front end framework, and some Java-desktop.

Recently my boss asked me whether I would do also back end for some project. It sounded like choice, not ultimatum.

I have small dilemma. I don't see much reason why I would like to learn back end. I prefer to become stronger in front end though (especially in react not the other framework they also use, which is less popular). If I switch to back end also, I see that as it would eat my time which I could have spent on front end and increase my skills in that direction.

I am also not very young, 33. I told him I would think about it. What can I do in such situation?

Comment: hi and welcome. I edited your Q a bit, feel free to roll back. Right now your question is not very specific. What do you want to achieve, where do you want to be in 5-10-15 years? This website is bad for getting opinions

Comment: @aaaaaa I thought many answers here are opinion based. This is not hard science like physics, so how come you want to disregard opinions in answers

Comment: "What can I do in such situation?" is too broad without "I want X, Y and Z, and to avoid W"

Answer (score 5):

At 33 you could easily have 25 more years software development ahead of you. Anything you can do at this point to widen your skills and experience is worth doing - you have no idea where your career may take you in the future. You should jump at the chance to work on something new, generalists are much more employable than specialists.

Comment: I would add that as you age, you will be competing with front end devs who are _much_ faster, cheaper and who can more easily cope with the rate of change in terms of the toolsets. In another 10 years, you will definitely be struggling to keep up, and in 25, you'll be either dead in the water, or stuck maintaining legacy stuff (from now). Don't waste the opportunity to pick up new and useful skills which won't change so quickly. (33? I'm in my 50s and still coding - I prefer it to anything else).

Answer (score 3):

> Recently my boss asked me whether I would do also back end for some
>   project. It sounded like choice, not ultimatum.
>
> What can I do in such situation?

You can decide if you want to do it or not.

If you do, reply "Certainly, boss! I'd be happy to do that."

If you do not, reply "I'd really rather not. I prefer to continue to work on front end tasks so that I can improve my skills there." and see how it goes.

In some shops, having a more rounded background would be a benefit. In other shops, working solely on front end tasks would be sufficient. After having been there for three years, you are likely in a position to make an informed decision and anticipate how your boss will react.